# Generate Unordered List with PHP with Relational Data

Tags: php, closures, tabular

I am trying to create an unordered list using data from a closure table query.

The result from the Query is returned with length of the relational table and breadcrumbs used to order the query result:

```
downline        length      breadcrumbs
Jack Black      0       3,4
John Seventeen      1       3,4,101
Pieter Betteerd     1       3,4,20
Andre Van Klerk     1       3,4,21
Hans Beyers         2       3,4,21,68
Cobus Ventering     1       3,4,22
Phillipus Sonkis    1       3,4,23
Andriet Joubert     2       3,4,23,58
Daniel Calitzdorp   1       3,4,63
Roelf Serfontein    2       3,4,63,81
Anke Van Blerk      3       3,4,63,81,83
Hermanus Pieters    1       3,4,69
Heinrich Brough     2       3,4,69,72
```

I want to output this result to an unordered list in html similar to this:

```
 <ul>
   <li>
       Jack Black 
       <ul>
         <li>John Seventeen</li>
         <li>Pieter Betteerd</li>
         <li>Andre Van Klerk
           <ul>
             <li>Hans Beyers</li>
           </ul>
         </li>
         <li>Cobus Ventering</li>
         <li>Phillipus Sonkis
           <ul>
             <li>Andriet Joubert</li>
           </ul>
         </li>
         <li>Daniel Calitzdorp
           <ul>
             <li>Roelf Serfontein
              <ul>
                <li>Anke Van Blerk</li>
              </ul>
             </li>
           </ul>
         </li>
         <li>Hermanus Pieters
           <ul>
             <li>Heinrich Brough</li>
           </ul>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to have it in XML but I now want to move it to jOrgChart and the unordered HTML code is required for the rendering of the Organizational Chart. My XML output was generated with this:
    $downline  = '
    
    
        
            
        
    ';
                        $count++;
                    } else {
                        $downline  .= '
    
        
            
        
    ';
                    }
                }
        $downline .= '
    ';
But I am clueless of how to implement this even after looking at recursive code. Maybe my brain is wired backwards, truly or I am just exhausted from sleep deprevation :P